# Connected vertex-transitive graphs of fixed chromatic number and arbitrary size

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

A simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is said to be *vertex-transitive* if for all $v,w\in V$ there is a [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) $\varphi:V\to V$ such that $\varphi(v) = w$.

The cyclic graphs $C_{2n+1}$ are vertex-transitive with chromatic number $3$.

Given any integers $k\geq 4$ and $n\geq k$, is there always a connected vertex-transitive graph $G=(V,E)$ with $\chi(G)=k$ and $|V|\geq n$?

Comment: What you call "homogeneous" is usually called "vertex-transitive": see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph

Comment: Interesting that the property of being homogeneous does not involve the quantified-over variables *v* and *w*, but does involve free variables *a* and *b*.

Comment: Thanks @SamHopkins - will correct this. And thanks user38.* -> I hope there are no more free variables enjoying their freedom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cartesian product of $K_k$ with $C_m$, where $km \geq n$ will do. It's vertex-transitive and has chromatic number $k$.

Comment: Or just take the complete $k$-partite graph $K_{m,m,\dots,m}$.